# C# => syntax for creating a variable

Tags: c#

The code below is used to initialise a store in some C# code I am looking at. However I do not understand the => syntax in this context.

Any ideas?

```
protected new ServiceRepositoryStore<T> Store => (ServiceRepositoryStore<T>) base.Store;
```

Comment: It's an [expression bodied property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members)

Comment: tl,dr: it is just shorthand for `{ get { return (ServiceRepositoryStore<T>) base.Store; } }`

Comment: Odd question for a 13.4k rep. and 38x famous question user

Comment: @CelsoLívero No-one is good at everything ;)

Comment: @Archer research is a good start and a person with these qualifications knows this

Comment: @CelsoLívero No offence meant, but judging someone in that way shows a lack of experience on your part.

Answer (score 6):

That is an example of an expression bodied read-only property:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx

It's a C# 6.0 feature and is the equivalent of:

```
protected new ServiceRepositoryStore<T> Store
{
    get
    {
        return (ServiceRepositoryStore<T>) base.Store;
    }
}
```